# "We aren’t going for the simple reason that we can’t afford it." (Is this sentence having dual meaning?)

Tags: interpretation

> "We aren’t going for the simple reason that we can’t afford it."

1. We aren't going for A (negate A) : A is not the reason. (We have another reason besides the simple reason)
2. We aren't going (negate going) : We are not going (We are not going because of the simple reason)

Literally, I think "We aren't going=We are not going=We don't go" and "for the simple reason that ~ = due to the fact that ~"

What's the meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We aren’t going [**for the simple reason that**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20the%20simple%20reason%20that) we can’t afford it.

means

> We aren’t going **because** we can’t afford it.

*Go* here simply means *travel or move to another place*.

> **We aren't going to** that expensive restaurant again.

Comment: I agree with Michael that the second meaning is possible. Though,you'll hear people say it as "We aren't 'not going because we can't afford it', we aren't going because..." — since all this gets messy, I would be more likely to say "It isn't that we can't afford it, we're not going because...."